# 1.why output is blank?

Tags: python, kivy

> I am am doing python kivy scroll view program there is no error but it gives me blank output

**in main python file**:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.stacklayout import StackLayout 
from kivy.metrics import dp

class stacklayoutexample(StackLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        for i in range(0,101):
            size = dp(100)
            b=Button(text=str(i), size_hint=(None,None), size=(size,size))
            # self.orientation = "rl-bt"
            # self.spacing = ("20dp","20dp")
            self.add_widget(b)
            

class main(App):
    pass

main().run()
```

**in main.kv file**:

```
scrollviewexample:
<scrollviewexample@ScrollView>:
    stacklayoutex:
    size_hint:1,None

<stacklayoutexample>:
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `kv`, you must capitalize all your classes. Also, is `stacklayoutex` intended to be `stacklayoutexample`? If so, here is a modified version of your code that I think will work:

main.kv:

```
Scrollviewexample:
<Scrollviewexample@ScrollView>:
    Stacklayoutexample:
        size_hint:1,None

<Stacklayoutexample>:
```

And the python code:

```
class Stacklayoutexample(StackLayout):  # just capitalized
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        for i in range(0, 101):
            size = dp(100)
            b = Button(text=str(i), size_hint=(None, None), size=(size, size))
            # self.orientation = "rl-bt"
            # self.spacing = ("20dp","20dp")
            self.add_widget(b)
```